# Scrapy: Selector returns full element with .get (but assigns data correctly)

Tags: python, get, scrapy, css-selectors

I have some issues to solve this matter. I try to solve with a similar problem posted in SO but it didn't work for me, so I have decided to ask to the community.

I have realized that my code works, getting the data that I asked for, but the print gives me the entire element, not only the class that I want from css.

So here is my code

```
def parse_links(self, response):

        content = ''

        with open('characters.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for line in f.read():
                content += line
                
        response = Selector(text=content)
        
        # loop over characters
        for character in response.css('article[class="item item_contains_branding item-multimedia-container"]'):
            print(characters.css('a[class="item-link"]::attr(href)').get)
```

As you can see, I create a file from the website .html and I want to obtain the class items from the css.

The result is the following when I print the results:

```
<bound method SelectorList.get of [<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::a[@class = 'item-link']/@href" data='/caracteristica/904/?xtmc=1_1_3000&xtcr=0'>]>
<bound method SelectorList.get of [<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::a[@class = 'item-link']/@href" data='/caracteristica/383/?xtmc=1_1_3000&xtcr=0'>]>
<bound method SelectorList.get of [<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::a[@class = 'item-link']/@href" data='/caracteristica/916/?xtmc=1_1_3000&xtcr=0'>]>
<bound method SelectorList.get of [<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::a[@class = 'item-link']/@href" data='/caracteristica/903/?xtmc=1_1_3000&xtcr=0'>]>
```

As you can see, I obtain the data for instance the last one `'/caracteristica/903/?xtmc=1_1_3000&xtcr=0'` but I don't need the entire sentences, only to the data get.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the representation of the actual `.get` method, not the result of calling it.

In simple terms, you're missing parentheses:

```py
print(characters.css('a[class="item-link"]::attr(href)').get())
```

Comment: This seems like it must have been answered before, but I'm unable to find anything...

Comment: Oh ... I do not know how it is possible that I could have passed that detail...It works fine...Thanks a lot.